# Debugging memory leaks in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there any good tool that helps with troubleshooting and debugging memory leaks in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [IE-Sieve](http://home.wanadoo.nl/jsrosman/)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome inspector have capabilities to take memory snapshots under profiles tab.

[DynaTrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey -- not sure about analyzing tools, but I know with my mac I can take a snapshot of a process and view it's trace of virtual addresses.
I don't know how much use this would be to you, but perhaps some?